# Updated to Swift 3 broke my swifty json code

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swifty-json

[image]I am new in Swift and I have been developing my first ios Application. Would you please advice me what to do? Today I converted my code to Swift 3 and now I can not start my app, because it displays me more than 20 errors in the SwiftyJson folder.

Is it possible to update my SwiftyJson code to swift 3 or any other ideas?

Comment: Did you check the SwiftyJson site for Swift 3 updates?

Comment: This is a very vague, open ended question. SwiftyJSON is updated for Swift 3.0. https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. If you haven't done so, I would suggest you update your Swifty JSON installation for the latest version and circle back with more specific question after you do that.

Comment: You might want to update your pods to use the `Swift 3` version. Add this to your pod file instead if not `pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/acegreen/SwiftyJSON.git', :branch => 'swift3'`

Comment: Thank you I think I can manage it now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this pod row `pod 'SwiftyJSON', '3.0.0'` in your pod file to add `SwiftyJSON` for `Swift 3.0`.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix this code which I updated

Comment: @Dakata, just declare `let reachability = Reachability()!`